# Can a Dataframe of NBA players be sorted by various conditions: to combine the rows of players w/ multiple entries bc they played on many teams?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, jupyter-notebook

I want to remove any players who didn't have over 1000 MP(minutes played).

I could easily write:

```
league_stats= pd.read_csv("1996.csv")
league_stats = league_stats.drop("Player-additional", axis=1)
league_stats_1000 = league_stats[league_stats['MP'] > 1000]
```

[image]

However, because players sometimes play for multiple teams in a year...this code doesn't account for that.

For example, Sam Cassell has four entries and none are above 1000 MP, but in total his MP for the season was over 1000. By running the above code I remove him from the new dataframe.

**I am wondering if there is a way to sort the Dataframe by matching Rank(the RK column gives players who played on different teams the same rank number for each team they played on) and then sort it by... if the total of their MP is 1000=<.**

*This is the page I got the data from: [1996-1997 season](https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1997_totals.html).
Above the data table and to the left of the blue check box there is a dropdown menu called "Share and Export". From there I clicked on "Get table as CSV (for Excel)". After that I saved the CSV to a text editor and change the file extension to .csv to upload it to Jupyter Notebook.*

**This is a solution I came up with:**

```
url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1997_totals.html'

df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

tot_df = df.loc[df['Tm'] == 'TOT']

mp_1000 = tot_df.loc[tot_df["MP"] < 1000]

# Create list of indexes with unnecessary entries to be removed. We have TOT and don't need these rows. 
# *** For the record, I came up with this list by manually going through the data.

indexes_to_remove = [5,6,24, 25, 66, 67, 248, 249, 447, 448, 449, 275, 276, 277, 19, 20, 21, 377, 378, 477, 478, 479,
                    54, 55, 451, 452, 337, 338, 156, 157, 73, 74, 546, 547, 435, 436, 437, 142, 143, 421, 42, 43, 232,
                     233, 571, 572, 363, 364, 531, 532, 201, 202, 111, 112, 139, 140, 307, 308, 557, 558, 93, 94, 512,
                     513, 206, 207, 208, 250, 259, 286, 287, 367, 368, 271, 272, 102, 103, 34, 35, 457, 458, 190, 191,
                     372, 373, 165, 166
                    ]

df_drop_tot = df.drop(labels=indexes_to_remove, axis=0)
df_drop_tot
```

Comment: I think you can group by name and age (insurance against players with same names), and change the MP to sum MP, then you can filter out the ones with less than 1000 MP and duplicates. However it's going to take some basketball knowledge to manually filter out the duplicates based on their most recent team since I don't think the table accounts for that.

Comment: thank you @JustJames. I think what I'm going to do is. Filter the dataframe by the column value **'TOT'** (This is the single row that totals a player's stats when they were on multiple teams).  From there I will I have two dataframes, one _with_ **'TOT'** and one _without_ **'TOT'**. I will remove players with **<1000 MP** from both dataframes. Then I will take the dataframe with **'TOT'** and now no players w/ **<1000MP** and add it to the other dataframe without **'TOT'** and no players w/ **<1000MP**.

Answer (score 1):

First off, no need to manually download the csv and then read it into `pandas`. You can load in the table using `pandas`' `.read_html()`.

And yes, you can simply get the list of ranks, player names, or whatever, that have greater than 1000 MP, then use that list to filter the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1997_totals.html'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
df = df[df['Rk'].ne('Rk')]  
df['MP'] = df['MP'].astype(int)

players_1000_rk_list = list(df[df['MP'] >= 1000]['Rk']) #<- coverts the "Rk" column into a list. I can then use that in the next line to only keep the "Rk" values that are in the list of "Rk"s that are >= 1000 MPs
players_df = df[df['Rk'].isin(players_1000_rk_list)]
```

**Output: filters down from 574 rows to 282 rows**

```
print(players_df)
      Rk               Player Pos Age   Tm   G  ...  AST  STL BLK  TOV   PF   PTS
0      1   Mahmoud Abdul-Rauf  PG  27  SAC  75  ...  189   56   6  119  174  1031
1      2  Shareef Abdur-Rahim  PF  20  VAN  80  ...  175   79  79  225  199  1494
3      4       Cory Alexander  PG  23  SAS  80  ...  254   82  16  146  148   577
7      6           Ray Allen*  SG  21  MIL  82  ...  210   75  10  149  218  1102
10     9        Greg Anderson   C  32  SAS  82  ...   34   63  67   73  225   322
..   ...                  ...  ..  ..  ...  ..  ...  ...  ...  ..  ...  ...   ...
581  430        Walt Williams  SF  26  TOR  73  ...  197   97  62  174  282  1199
582  431   Corliss Williamson  SF  23  SAC  79  ...  124   60  49  157  263   915
583  432         Kevin Willis  PF  34  HOU  75  ...   71   42  32  119  216   842
589  438      Lorenzen Wright   C  21  LAC  77  ...   49   48  60   79  211   561
590  439       Sharone Wright   C  24  TOR  60  ...   28   15  50   93  146   390

[282 rows x 30 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the .read_html() tip! I do have a few questions. I entered your code, commented it out, & then ran each line one by one. I don't understand lines 4,6, and 7.  the `.ne()` function will return false if two values are equal to each other. I don't see how it plays a role here. Also for line 6 I don't understand why `['RK']` is after `df[df['MP'] >= 1000]`. I understand what line 7 does but I don't understand the notation. Otherwise the code is great & I'll just filter out rows with "TOT"(total) so I don't have excess values when calculating. I'll share the code I came up w/

Comment: meant to tag you in above comment. I do like your method and feel that I can use it and part of mine(where I remove the rows containing `'TOT'`). I just don't understand _how_ parts of your code work @chitown88

Comment: also, I'm using `read_html()` and I understand why you used `.ne()`. When you manually create a CSV there is no value of "Rk" in the `Rk` column. But now that I'm using `read_html()` i see the extra row. @chitown88

Comment: I'll edit my post shortly to explain.

Comment: Ok added the comement. Basically is to make that `Rk` columns into a list, then using that list to keep the valid rows. Much the same way you did with the index, only doing it programatically as opposed to manually.